# tile based side scrolling flickers

Tags: horizontal-scrolling

I'm doing a little platform game in the html5 canvas element, like probably a lot others at the moment. I have very little game programmering experience hence this is my first game where I'll try to move things around "pixel wise" instead of moving everything on tile at a time.

I've got everything down up untill the sidescrolling of the game!
The tiles are scrolling correctly, but still scrolling one tile at a time.

I use the map position to find the correct tiles:
tile based side scrolling flickers
    loopStartX = mapPosX/tileWidth

And I use another counter to print them relative to the screen, this allways starts at zero.

```
tilePosX = counter*tileWidth;
```

Then I thought about subtracting this:

```
 mapPosX % tileWidth
```

From the x-position to get a smooth scrolling, it works a little - but everytime loopStartX increases something is flickering back and forth, can't really figure it out.

I know I'm doing something wrong, but can't seem to figure out what.

Any help is appreciated!

Have a good day.

**UPDATE - CODE SNIPPETS:**

Max view Point

```
this.maxViewX = this.map[0].length*this.blockWidth-this.mapWidthPx-1;
```

Player speed

```
//Player moving speed (posX)
    this.xVel = 4;
```

This is runned every game loop in the player object:

Moving Left:

```
//Now control player movement vs viewpoint
if(this.posX<256 && game.viewPointX>0) {
    game.viewPointX -= this.xVel;
if(game.viewPointX<0) game.viewPointX = 0;
            } else {
                this.posX -= this.xVel;
            }
```

Moving right

```
//Now control player movement vs viewpoint
            if(this.posX>384 && game.viewPointX<game.maxViewX) {
                game.viewPointX += this.xVel;
                if(game.viewPointX>game.maxViewX) game.viewPointX = game.maxViewX;
            } else {
                this.posX += this.xVel;
            }
```

This is runned every game loop in the game object

```
//Updating viewpoint
        //Calculating start values for the for-loops when drawing the tiles from 2d intArray map
        //Also used for collision detection
        this.viewStartX = Math.round(this.viewPointX/this.blockWidth)-1;
        if(this.viewStartX<0) this.viewStartX = 0;
        this.viewEndX = this.viewStartX+22;
        this.scrollSmoothX = (this.viewPointX%this.blockWidth);
```

Here's when I draw the blocks

```
var posY = posX = 0;
        //Looping through Y
        for(var i in this.map) {

            //Looping X
            for(var j=this.viewStartX, xc=0; j<this.viewEndX; j++, xc++) {
                if(this.map[i][j]!=0) {
                    var tile = this.tilesetIndex[this.map[i][j]];
                    posX = xc*this.blockWidth+tile[4]-this.scrollSmoothX;
                    posY = (i*this.blockHeight+tile[5]);
                    game.canvas.ctx.drawImage(this.tileset,
                        tile[0], //sliceX
                        tile[1], //sliceY
                        tile[2], //width ??
                        tile[3], //height ??
                        posX, //poxX
                        posY, //posY
                        tile[2], //width ??
                        tile[3]);//height ??
                }
            }
        }
```

The "tile[4]" and "tile[5]" are extra padding for the image - used for image like block edges that's not as big as this.tileWidth and this.tileHeight.

- jack

Comment: For creating Canvas based apps, there is a lot of rocks to fell on, you should try using some framework. Anyway, we cant help you, if we cant see your situation/code. Give use example, or link to your project testing area.

Comment: I've added some code snippets - let me know if you need more.

Comment: Also, could you tell me more about those rocks? Are they concerning cross browser - or something else? I'd like to stick with my own code, for learning purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use origin displacement, don't redraw tiles, cause its too heavy and unnessesary. See [tutorial](http://www.canvasdemos.com/2009/07/09/game-development-tutorials/).

Comment: Just to be clear - what it means is that I should draw all the images once - and then hide/show those with in/out view?

Comment: Depends on each situation. Idea is to seperate construction from movement. At first, you construct with loops the things/objects you need, after that, you move those contructions around as a whole.

Comment: Yeah I got the point now. But when trying the game from the tutorial you linked, my CPU is going up to like 25% - and that's just the man running with no boxes. My own game; a big map with boxes and coins (objects) - my CPU usage barely raises. So I'm a little confused - shouldn't the tutorial example use less machine power than my code?

Comment: That tutorial is only as example for method of h-scroll in-game. It has very high FPS demand, that is why it is so resource greedy. If I would develop, I would create something, that fixes camera on the character all the time (that means, there is no one-axis scrolling, it's both axis), and char/terrain collision borders should be worked much more carefully. That site has many good example for methods, but most of them are not optimized for less resource usage, they dont care :)